# Proof verification: AB5) implies AB4) in Grothendieck's Tohoku paper

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, abelian-categories

Following the proof outlined in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/170985/79527), I wanted to show that when

$$\begin{alignedat}{3}
0 \longrightarrow \mathord{} & K_j & \mathord{} \longrightarrow \mathord{} & A_j & \mathord{} \longrightarrow \mathord{} & B_j \\
& \downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow \\
0 \longrightarrow \mathord{} & K & \mathord{} \longrightarrow \mathord{} & A & \mathord{} \longrightarrow \mathord{} & B \\
\end{alignedat}$$

commutes, the rightmost arrow being mono and both rows being exact, then the left square is a pullback. However, I only needed the bottom row to be exact at $ A $, which threw me off a bit:

If you have
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U@>>>A_j\\
@VVV @VVV\\
K @>>> A
\end{CD}
$$

Then by exactness at $ A $ and commutativity, you have
$$\begin{CD}
U @>>> A_j @>>> B_j\\
@.@.@VVV\\
@.@.B
\end{CD}$$
equal to $ 0 $, and then because $ B_j \longrightarrow B $ is mono, $ U \longrightarrow A_j $ factors uniquely through $ K_j \longrightarrow A_j $. The other leg of the pullback diagram commutes by uniqueness of the kernel factorisation through $ K \longrightarrow A $.

Does that proof seem correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you really need the bottom row to be exact at $K$ and not necessarily at $A$.

Indeed, to get the factorisation of $U\to A_j$ through $K_j$ you need to prove that the composition $U\to A_j\to B_j$ is zero, and for this you only need to know that $K\to A\to B$ is zero, which is weaker than exactness at $A$.

On the other hand, to prove that the second leg of the pullback commutes, you use the uniqueness of the factorisation through $K$, or in other words, the fact that $K\to A$ is a monomorphism, which is equivalent to the exactness of $0\to K\to A$ at $K$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a shame I didn't notice the missing assumption...